# InfoBox button to switch to street view

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have a button within an infobox. I want that button to switch to street view. The button gets triggered and switches to street view however my code below treats street view as an entirely separete entity to my google map which means I cannot zoom out back to map view and there is no visible marker on street view level:

```
        var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(this.marker[id].position.jb,this.marker[id].position.kb);

    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
        }
    };

    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), panoramaOptions);
    this.gmap.setStreetView(panorama);
```

How do I modify this so that streetview is triggered within the current map rather than creating an entirely separete instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    var streetViewMaxDistance = 100;          

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(this.marker[id].position.jb,this.marker[id].position.kb);
    var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    var panorama = this.gmap.getStreetView();

    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(point, streetViewMaxDistance, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {

        if(status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK){

            var oldPoint = point;
            point = streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng;

            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(point,oldPoint);            

            panorama.setPosition(point);
            panorama.setPov({
                heading: heading,
                zoom: 1,
                pitch: 0
            });
            panorama.setVisible(true);

        }else{
            // no street view available in this range, or some error occurred
            console.log("Sorry! Street View is not available.");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this may also be useful. To integrate this with my existing map where:

`map` is my google map instantiated class `map = new google.maps.Map(el,mapOptions)`

`pointer` is my instantiated marker:

```
    pointer = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
```

And latLng is: `latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)`

All I needed to do was add the following code below everything else, which listens for a click on my marker, when it is clicked it sets street view to visible.

```
    var panorama = map.getStreetView();
    panorama.setPosition(latLng);
    panorama.setPov({
        heading: 45,
        pitch:-10}
    );

    google.maps.event.addListener(pointer, 'click', function() {
        panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using null for the setStreetView method parameter will bind the embedded street view to the current map (complete with an X to close the street view and return to the map).

```
this.gmap.setStreetView();
```

From:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Map

Binds a StreetViewPanorama to the map. This panorama overrides the default StreetViewPanorama, allowing the map to bind to an external panorama outside of the map. Setting the panorama to null binds the default embedded panorama back to the map.

Edit: If you have multiple infowindows you may need to use a function like this, in order to update the streeview with the position of the marker:

```
function streetview(location) {

    location = location.replace('(', '').replace(')', '');
    var lat = location.split(',')[0];
    var lng = location.split(',')[1];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    this.gmap.setStreetView();
    this.gmap.getStreetView().setPosition(latlng);
}
```